# Concatenate string with NULL itself

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can i make this part of query return NULL?

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX),
@Date DATETIME = NULL

SET @SQL = 'SELECT ' + CASE WHEN @Date IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @Date) END
EXEC(@SQL)
```

PS: NULL and '' is not the same in this example. If i'll try to insert the result of this query into db i'll get:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

Is there any analogue to c#'s "DBNull.Value" value in SQL?

PS2: well ELSE NULL is not redundant i think. I need to pass NULL value to insert script if no date param was passed. Just like:

```
INSERT INTO [AccDocuments].[DOCUMENT].[Documents] 
([Some_Date]) 
VALUES (CASE WHEN @Date IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @Date) END)
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? The query you're constructing doesn't make any sense since (for non-NULL `@Date` values) it's inserting an unquoted string into the select statement, so you'd generate e.g. `SELECT 2014-04-01 10:30:20` which will just generate an error because it's not valid SQL.

Comment: i'm trying to pass NULL value as param to procedure if param was not pushed to the script, else - i convert incoming date to string and executing script

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever this can be avoided if vlaue is encloses in qoutes and then value is inserted

Comment: You seem to have broken (some) problem down into lots of very little pieces, and you're asking a question about one of those little pieces. We might be able to offer much better answers if you could give us the whole picture. Is the overall goal just to perform an `INSERT` into another table? If so, why are you building it up as a string at all?

Comment: 1. value of NULL cannot be concatenated with string
2. empty string enclosed in quotes becomes '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' when inserted in datetime field

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Date DATETIME = NULL

SELECT CASE WHEN @Date IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @Date) ELSE @Date END as date
```

It will return `CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @Date)` if `@Date` is not null, and returns `@Date` itself (which is null) otherwise.

See the result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/32527).

Comment: Is this just swapping around the expressions in the `CASE` expression (and then eliminating the redundant `ELSE NULL`)? It sometimes helps, when giving an answer that looks quite similar to the question, to highlight what you've actually changed.

Comment: @AndriiHorda: See the fiddle example in my answer.

Comment: you're missing the main point:

`DECLARE @Date as datetime,
        @SQL as nvarchar(max)

SET @Date=NULL

SET @SQL = 'SELECT' + CASE WHEN @Date IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @Date) ELSE @Date END
PRINT (@SQL)`

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to enclose your not null values in escaped qoutes

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX),
@Date datetime=getdate() 

SET @SQL = 'SELECT ' +CASE WHEN @Date IS NULL THEN NULL 
                           ELSE ''''+ cast(@Date as nvarchar(max))+'''' END
print @sql
EXEC(@SQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

`CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL` will come into play here. Your query, if @Date is `NULL`, will result in a NULL string because you are concatenating `NULL` into a string and I have a feeling that `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL` is on by default.

However I think you want to end up with a string like `'SELECT NULL'`, am I right? In which case your statement needs to read:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Date DATETIME = NULL

SET @SQL = 'SELECT ' + CASE WHEN @Date IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @Date) END
EXEC(@SQL)
```

Note the single quotes around `NULL` in the true part of the `CASE` statement. I'm not sure why you'd get a conversion error.

Comment: NULL != 'NULL' and 
'NULL' can't be pushed into datetime column as insertion value

Comment: Yes it does because you are using dynamic SQL. When you execute the SQL statement you are passing a string to be interpreted and executed. If you do `EXEC('INSERT INTO MyTable(DateColumn) SELECT NULL')` it will insert NULL into your date column (assuming it is nullable). Are you saying that if `@Date` is null then you don't want to insert anything? If that's the case then you would need two alternative statements. This has the whiff of an XY problem. Why not try publishing the WHOLE query (including any 'INSERT') and not just a bit of it? That way people may be able to help better.

Comment: Instead of CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @Date) we should enclose this in single quotes, and format to ISO 8601: '''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @Date, 126) + ''''